# Issue understanding a parameter expansion in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, parameters

I am trying to understand what a parameter expansion does inside a bash script.

**third_party_bash_script**

```
#!/bin/sh
files="${*:--}"
# For my understanding I tried to print the contents of files
echo $files 

pkill bb_stream
if [ "x$VERBOSE" != "" ]; then
        ARGS=-v1
fi
while [ 1 ]; do cat $files; done | bb_stream $ARGS
```

When I run `./third_party_bash_script`, all it prints is a hyphen `-` and nothing else. Since it did not make sense to me, I also tried to experiment with it in the terminal

```
$ set one="1" two="2" three="3"
$ files="${*:--}"
$ echo $files
one="1" two="2" three="3"
$ set four="4"
$ files="${*:--}"
four="4"
```

I can't seem to understand what it's doing. Could someone kindly help me with the interpretation of `${*:--}` by the `sh`?

Comment: Note that `"x$VERBOSE"` will **never** be an empty string, due to the leading "x".  Use this to test if a variable is not empty: `[ -n "$VERBOSE" ]` . Also `while [ 1 ]` is not using "1" as a boolean value: it is a non empty string, and when `[...]` gets one argument, and it is non-empty, the `[` command exits "true".

Comment: @glennjackman what does `"x$VERBOSE"` expand to?

Comment: The letter "x" followed by the contents of the variable. If the variable is empty, you still have the non-empty string "x". This idiom is useful only for extremely ancient shells. It is no longer needed. Use the [`-n` and `-z` operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-test) instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`"$@"` is an **array** of the arguments passed to your script, `"$*"` is a **string** of all of those arguments concatenated with blanks in between.

`"${*:--}"` is the string of arguments if any were provided (`:-`), or `-` otherwise which means "take input from stdin" otherwise.

`"${@:--}"` is the array of arguments if any were provided (`:-`), or `-` otherwise which means "take input from stdin" otherwise.

```
$ cat file
foo
bar
```

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '{ print FILENAME, $0 }' "${@:--}"
```

When an arg is provided to the script, `"$@"` contains `"file"` so that is the arg that awk is called with:

```
$ ./tst.sh file
file foo
file bar
```

When no arg is provided to the script, `"$@"` is empty so awk is called with `-` (meaning read from stdin) as it's arg:

```
$ cat file | ./tst.sh
- foo
- bar
```

You almost always want to use `"${@:--}"` rather than `"${*:--}"` in this context, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571/what-is-the-difference-between-and for more info on `"$@"` vs `"$*"`.

Answer (score 2):

`${param:-default}` expands to the value of `$param` if `$param` is set and not empty, otherwise it expands to `default`.

`$*` is all the command-line arguments to the script.

In `${*:--}`, `param` is `*` and `default` is `-`. If `$*` is not an empty string, it expands to the script arguments. If it's empty, it expands to the default value `-`.

This can be used in a script to implement the common behavior that a program reads from the files listed in its arguments, and reads from standard input if no filename arguments are given. Many commands treat an input filename argument `-` as standing for the standard input.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** addressing  OP's original, pre-edited post ...

See [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for a brief review of different options.

While the other answers reference the use of `${*:--}` (and `${@:--}`) as a alternate means of reading from stdin, OP's sample script is a bit simpler ... if the variable `$*` (ie, script's command line args) is empty then replace with the literal string `-`.

We can see this with a few examples:

```
$ third_party_bash_script
-

$ third_party_bash_script a b c
a b c

$ echo 'a b c' | third_party_bash_script
-
```

If we replace `${*:--}` with `${*:-REPLACEMENT}`:

```
$ third_party_bash_script
REPLACEMENT

$ third_party_bash_script a b c
a b c

$ echo 'a b c' | third_party_bash_script
REPLACEMENT
```

I'm guessing in OP's actual script there's more going on with the `$files` variable so in order to know for sure how the `${*:--}` is being processed we'd need to see the actual script and how it's referencing the `$files` variable.

---

As for OP's `set|files=|echo` code snippets:

```
$ set one="1" two="2" three="3"
$ files="${*:--}"
$ echo $files
one=1 two=2 three=3
```

We can see the same behavior from the script with:

```
$ third_party_bash_script one="1" two="2" three="3"
one=1 two=2 three=3
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have updated my post with the actual usage of `files`.